# How to resolve django rest_framework error "Method \"POST\" not allowed."?

Tags: python, django

Sorry I'm still a beginner on django I would like to create an endpoint with django rest_framework allowing me to create an HD wallet and backup in database, but I have an error:

> "Method "POST" not allowed ."

So I created this model that represented hdwallet:

```
from typing import Any
from django.db import models, transaction
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class HDWallet(models.Model):
    """HDWallet class"""

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    private_key: str = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    address: str = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="wallet",
    )

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    @transaction.atomic
    def disable(self) -> Any:
        if self.active is False:
            # Ne faisons rien si la wallet est déjà désactivée
            return
        self.active = False
        self.save()
        self.currencies.update(active=False)
```

also I created my serializers class:

```
class HDWalletSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HDWallet
        fields = "__all__"

    def post(self, request: Request) -> Any:
        user = User.objects.get(username=request["username"])
        name = f"{user.username}_{user.id}"
        wallet = Wallet.create(name)
        if user is not None:
            hdwallet = HDWallet.objects.create(
                {
                    "name": name,
                    "private_key": wallet.get_key(),
                    "address": wallet.get_key().address,
                    "user": user.id,
                }
            )
        else:
            raise Exception("use do not exist")

        return Response(
            {
                "status": 201,
                "message": "wallet have been successfully created!",
                "data": hdwallet,
            }
        )
```

and my view in views.py:

```
class HDWalletCreateView(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = HDWalletSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsUser, IsUserAuthenticated, IsAdminAuthenticated]
```

and the this is the URL:

```
# we create your router
router = routers.SimpleRouter()

# we register all url
router.register("wallet/create", HDWalletCreateView, basename="wallet-create"),

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api/", include(router.urls)),
]
```

but when I run the endpoint to postman I have this error:

> "detail": "Method "POST" not allowed."

I don't know where is the problem

Comment: are you authenticated? because you defined the permissions as needing auth, so if not auth you probably won't be authorized to POST. Do you get a 405 or a 401/403 in Postman?

Comment: I got 405 in postman, but when I run the endpoint on postman I'm authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to create a CRUD like that, the good think is to use the ModelViewSets, Rather than creating our URLs and redefining our methods one by one, DRF offers inheritable classes for our views, which are the ModelViewsets.
They allow the rapid implementation of all CRUD actions for a given model.
Using a ModelViewset requires using another way of defining our URLs. This is done through a router. You can Juste declared your Serializer

```
class HDWalletSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HDWallet
        fields = "__all__"
```

Your views will look like this

```
class HDWalletCRUDViewset(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = HDWalletSerializer

    def get_queryset(self) -> Any:
        return HDWallet.objects.filter(active=True)
```

at the end, to access to the endpoint, you can get this code:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from wallet.views import (
    HDWalletCRUDViewset,
)

router = routers.SimpleRouter()

# we register all url
router.register("wallets", HDWalletCRUDViewset, basename="wallets")

urlpatterns = [
    path("api/", include(router.urls)),
]
```

Notice that the router use the viewset to do all action

Answer (score 0):

finally I resolved the problem, I falled on the web documents who help me to have a good understand of how to perform crud using DRF. So that is the solution and I will put the link to the web tutorial at the end.
the model of my wallet class didn't change:

```
class HDWallet(models.Model):
    """HDWallet class"""

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    private_key: str = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    address: str = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="wallet",
    )

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

that is my serializer class:

```
class HDWalletSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HDWallet
        fields = "__all__"
```

that is my views file:

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST", "DELETE"])
def wallet_list(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        wallets = HDWallet.objects.all()

        name = request.query_params.get("name", None)
        if name is not None:
            wallets = wallets.filter(name=name)

        tutorials_serializer = HDWalletSerializer(wallets, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(tutorials_serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == "POST":
        wallet_data = request.data
        wallet_serializer = HDWalletSerializer(data=wallet_data)
        if wallet_serializer.is_valid():
            wallet_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(wallet_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JsonResponse(
            wallet_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )

    elif request.method == "DELETE":
        count = HDWalletSerializer.objects.all().delete()
        return JsonResponse(
            {"message": "{} Tutorials were deleted successfully!".format(count[0])},
            status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT,
        )


@api_view(["GET", "PUT", "DELETE"])
def wallet_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        wallet = HDWallet.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except HDWallet.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse(
            {"message": "The wallet does not exist"},
            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        )

    if request.method == "GET":
        wallet_serializer = HDWalletSerializer(wallet)
        return JsonResponse(wallet_serializer.data)

    elif request.method == "PUT":
        wallet_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        wallet_serializer = HDWalletSerializer(wallet, data=wallet_data)
        if wallet_serializer.is_valid():
            wallet_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(wallet_serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(
            wallet_serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
        )

    elif request.method == "DELETE":
        wallet.delete()
        return JsonResponse(
            {"message": "Wallet was deleted successfully!"},
            status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT,
        )


@api_view(["GET"])
def wallet_list_published(request):
    wallets = HDWallet.objects.filter(published=True)

    if request.method == "GET":
        wallets_serializer = HDWalletSerializer(wallets, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(wallets_serializer.data, safe=False)
```

and finally the urls file:

```
from django.urls import path
from wallet.views import (
    wallet_detail,
    wallet_list,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path("api/wallets/", wallet_list),
    path("api/wallets/<pk>/", wallet_detail),
]

so that's the result here on image
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

We have certains configurations to do, I put the tutorial link for who want to have more explanation:

[enter link description here][1]
```

https://www.bezkoder.com/django-rest-api/